# How to create Custom Delegate of UITextField in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to create Custom delegate of UITextField

My code is like this

In CustomTableView

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldEndEditing:)])
    {
        [self.delegate textFieldShouldEndEditing:textField];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

In View Controller

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
```

But this method is not getting call in ViewController.
Can Any body please tell me what I am doing wrong

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how to assign delegate in viewcontroller ?

Comment: I assume `self.delegate = viewController`, can you check if its' nil?

Answer (score 1):

You should not call textField's delegates methods manually like `[self.delegate textFieldShouldEndEditing:textField];`

If you want to call your delegate method from another class then make some method which is not provided by `sdk`!

for example make method like,

```
- (BOOL)myTextFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
```

and call this method from your other class by your `self.delegate` and make sure that `self.delegate` is not `nil`, i mean it have object of your `viewController`!

Comment: Lion `can't call` should be `shouldn't call` in your answer. Since the user can call the delegate methods manually but that's not  a good idea.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : Yeah ! Edited answer. It was a typo! Thanks for suggesion. :)

Comment: @Lion Its not getting call. Can you please share some more code.

Comment: @Lion not an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a custom TextField class and also set delegate in that class. Like this

.h File

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

.m File

```
@implementation CustomTextField
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.delegate = self;
    }
return self;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: I create class same as you say but nothing get call.